# Influxdb2 data migration/transformation

Tags: grafana, flux, telegraf, influxdb-2

I have a bucket which stores data received via `telegraf` as timeseries. The original datasource is `mqtt` so the fields in the single data frames in the bucket are basically the topic layout of the mqtt subscription.

Now the mqtt publisher will change the topic layout - which will result in different fields (fieldnames) in the dataframe. Since I'm using `grafana` on these buckets this will lead to problems.

Is there a "standard" way to achieve a **migration/transformation of the old dataframes to the new layout?** Couldn't find a conclusive answer in google or SO.

My intuitive approach would be to create corresponding flux queries like:

```
from(bucket: "bucketWithOldFormat")
    |> map(fn: (r) => ({r with _time: .....)
    |> to(bucket: "bucketWithNewFormat")
```